# Navigation2 support for 3D navigation (Drones)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A stretch goal of navigation2 is to support 3D navigation. Is there any update on that case or still navigation2 is only for wheel robots?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341594/navigation2-support-for-3d-navigation-(drones)/) by [GeorgeG](https://answers.ros.org/users/41788/georgeg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-01-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-13**:
Perhaps @stevemacenski could provide some insight.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-13**:
I'm gone for 1 week for CES and get pulled right back in on Monday ;-)

See answer below.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-14**:
:) just thought you'd be the one in-the-know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So. Yeah.

When we say "3D navigation", by  that I mean "navigating in 3D", ei navigating in non-flat environments. This is different than a flight drone, but I have intentionally left the APIs in 3D to support it should someone have appropriate planner and controllers to accomplish the task.

To your more specific question, no. No work has been done to support drones, nor do I expect any work from my end to be done to support drones in the near term or long term future. This could change if there is a group interested in that support and willing to work for it, but I have no use for it and Navigation2 is currently primarily targeted to the class of ground vehicles, hopefully to include quadrupeds, ackermann steering cars, and more in the near-ish term future.

If this is an area  **you** find compelling and have need for, we should discuss that and what a roadmap might look like to help make that a reality. I have no qualms helping folks implement the framework changes required and merging the algorithms to support, but its not something in the cards for my personal CPU cycles.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorgemia](https://answers.ros.org/users/52277/jorgemia/) on 2020-11-16**:
@stevemacenski does navigation 2 already support navigation/path planning in outdoor/3D terrain for wheeled ground robots then? Any tutorials anywhere to navigate in 3D terrain?